# Font Awesome Icons only squares

Tags: icon, fonts

I have a problem with the icons of font awesome. They are showing, though not all. Some icons just show a square and I don’t know how to fix it.

So this is how it looks like:

[image]

If I go to the console and remove the tick on “font” and “font-family” it will appear again correctly.
I can’t understand why

[image]

So how can I delete these properties?

Comment: Are you loading in 2 versions of FA?  Check the page source and see.

Comment: No just one. For some reason I could fixed it by insert a custom CSS  code: `.fa.fa-dashboard:before {
    content: "\f3fd" !important;
}` but I have no clue why it works...

Comment: Check what version you are using and make sure your only using icons from the version.

Answer (score 1):

In typography, a square appears when you ask for a character that is not included in the font.

By adding the property *!important* to *font-family:*, your naviagator is obliged to use Font Awesome.

Look carefully at your two screenshots. Neither of the icons is identical.

**Some solutions:**

1. Modify your css

   .fa{
   font-family: 'font-awesome';
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1
   }
2. Use a other icon font
3. Make sure you call the Unicode character: f0e4

I hope this will help you.